# Ajax Dropdown to populate Province and City

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using Ajax for my dropdown to select Province and City.

I wanted the City to be populated after I choose Province.

I already have my code but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Here are my codes

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function provChange(){
  var province = $("#province_id").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php //echo $this->Html->url('/front/ajax_city_id'); ?>/"+province+"/<?php //echo $this->request->data('Car.city_id'); ?>",cache: false,
    success: function(msg){$("#city_id").html(msg); },
    "statusCode": {
      403: function() {
        window.location.href="<?php //echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'front','action'=>'index')); ?>"
      },
      500: function() {
        alert('Error Server Side occured');
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

view.ctp

```
<div class="emBeli form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('provinsi',array('type'=>'select','empty'=>'Provinsi','options'=>$provinsis,'id'=>'province_id','class'=>'form-control form-control-custom','label'=>false,'onChange'=>'provChange()')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('kota',array('type'=>'select','empty'=>'Kota','options'=>$kota,'class'=>'form-control form-control-custom','label'=>false)); ?>
</div>
```

ajax_city_id.ctp

```
<?php
if ($key==null) echo "<option value=\"\">Kota</option>";
    foreach($types as $i):
            if($i['Kota']['id']==$key) echo "<option value=\"".$i['Kota']['id']."\" selected>".$i['Kota']['name']."</option>";
            else echo "<option value=\"".$i['Kota']['id']."\">".$i['Kota']['name']."</option>";
    endforeach;
?>
```

controller.php

```
public function ajax_city_id($id = null, $key = null, $cur = null)
{
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->set('types', $this->Kota->find('all', array('conditions' => array('display' => 1, 'Kota.province_id =' => $id), 'order' => array('Kota.name' => 'asc'))));
    $this->set('key', $key);
}
```

all i got is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
which means it can't find variable $("#province_id") on my javascript code.

please somebody help......

Comment: I would assume the reference is saying it can't find the jquery library, have you included it? You could test this by removing the line : $("#province_id").val(); and seeing if it gives you the same error when it hits $.ajax

Comment: yes it gives me the same error.. @codycollicott actually i included the javascript on view.ctp

Comment: Then you just need to include jquery in your project here is a ref example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980308/setting-up-cakephp-to-use-jquery

Comment: it's still giving error :( @codycollicott

Comment: Could you check your source code or network and make sure that jquery is running on that page?

Comment: Did you check [Chained Dropdowns](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples) ? It contains the live examples and code.